# HTML 5 in Magento Go

Tags: html, magento, magento-go

When I use Magneto Go, it strips out my HTML 5 tag.   and  are stripped out every time after I save.

How can I use HTML 5 in the Magento Go?

Using the CMS to edit my page (Content -> Hide Editor) and then copying and paste code.

Comment: This is more of a user question than a programming question. Magento Go is a paid service and has it's own [support](https://go.magento.com/cases/index/create/) and [forum](http://collaborate.magento.com/magento), I expect they are better equiped than an open community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  Magento Go is a hosted service without a public extension API (there's a data gathering/setting api, similar to the host application's SOAP api).  You'd need to install an extension from their marketplace that enabled HTML 5, but I don't think such a thing exists.  Your best bet will be to take this up with the platform vendor's support.

Comment: Quite disappointing... I guess that explains the price.  Anyone have any experience / recommendations with any other e-commerce platform designed to sell a handful of items w/ easy checkout?  Funny how the easy projects always become a pain!